Squeak cannot locate the sources file named /Applications/SqueakV60.sources on MacOS
I'm new to Smalltalk. I decided I'd give it a shot and see what it was about.
I decided on Squeak as my flavour of the day, went to the site and installed the Squeak 6.0 universal Mac app and threw it into my applications folder like I do with all other .app files.
When it came to save an image of my environment, it saved inside the Squeak6.0.app folder by default, and in there it works flawlessly.
As soon as I move the .image and .changes files outside that folder and try running the image I'm met with this popup:

The weird thing is that the image seems to be working fine.
I can follow along in code examples without issue, I'm just worried that something may actually break.
Is there a way I can keep my images in my projects folder without having it live inside of the .app?

Welcome to Squeak! I can't answer your question directly because I do not use macOS but I have forwarded it to the Squeak developers' mailing list: https://lists.squeakfoundation.org/archives/list/squeak-dev@lists.squeakfoundation.org/thread/SV3L5K5G6HZZZVY3OIYZXZQMKH56KGUF/ I hope you will have success!

Squeak looks for the .sources file in specific locations (see the method SmalltalkImage>>#sourcesFilePaths for reference):

Path of the VM
Path of the Image file
On Unix (Linux etc):

/usr/share/squeak/
/usr/local/share/squeak/



The first (VM-path) is special on OSX, because it also means the location of the .app itself.
So when your Squeak.app (or silmilar) is in /Applications/, Squeak will look for the .sources there first.
Solutions

You can put the SqueakV60.source in /Applications. This will work for all images started with your Squeak.app that lives there.
You can put the SqueakV60.source next to your .image file for every image. This has worked for you so far, because the .image and .sources are both in the Resouces folder of the .app.

I would recommend the first option.
Background
Squeak uses .sources files to look up source code for various methods. This is done to have the images a little bit "slimmer", as opposed to storing the method's source code in the image (which is possible but not always done).
For that, each major release (and some special point releases) has the vast majority of it's method's source code in the respecivve SqueakV??.sources file.
(Note that the .changes file of the image serves a similar purpose, but for methods that you or others change for your inidivual image).
As @timRowledge points out, the image can happily live without the sources, but browsing source code is not as fun anymore.

OK, first thing is to reassure you that nothing will break. The browsers can decompile the code to show you what is there BUT it can't work out what the comments should be and local variable names will usually appear as 't1' etc. Which one can live with temporarily but is not ideal.
The quick solution is to copy (not move - that will annoy you later, almost certainly)the .sources file to the folder you are saving your image in. One might expect making an alias would work but my experience is that Mac OS still can't get that right.
Do please join the Squeak mailing list; meet new people!

I was afraid that adding the source file to the other folder would somehow pollute the namespace or do other weird things, glad I can just copy it
